# The problem to perform migration in .NET version 8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I changed the package version from 8.0.2 to 8.0.0, but it didn't help.
The project has no errors, but the migration gives errors

Error :

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[OccupyPassway.Domain.DataBaseContext]' while attempting to activate 'OccupyPassway.Domain.DataBaseContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

DataBaseContext :

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        
    }

    private DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

ConfigureService :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using OccupyPassway.Domain.Repository;
using OccupyPassway.Domain.Repository.Interface;

namespace OccupyPassway.Domain;

public static class ConfigureServices
{
    public static IServiceCollection DomainConfig(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlite("Data Source=DbLite.db");
        });

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));

        return services;
    }
}
```

program :

```
using OccupyPassway.Domain;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.DomainConfig();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.Run();
```

Comment: You can use the `dotnet list package` command in the VS package manager console to check which packages are installed and their versions.

Comment: all package version 8.0.2

Comment: Top-level Package                                  Requested   Resolved
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore                    8.0.2       8.0.2   
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions       8.0.2       8.0.2   
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design             8.0.2       8.0.2   
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite             8.0.2       8.0.2   
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design      1.1.6       1.1.6   
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools              8.0.2       8.0.2

Comment: You can try to register dbcontext in program.cs and then rebuild your project and retest.

    `builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=DbLite.db");
    });`

Comment: not worked and again this Erorr

Comment: You can try commenting out the line`services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));` and regenerating it, or can you share your `IGenericRepository` and `GenericRepository` codes?